# ngClass doesn't evaluate

Tags: angular, ng-class

When ngClass is used in Object - keys manner it does not evaluate right. For example if I have in html:

```
    <div [ngClass]="{'cbold': bold, 'citalic': italic, 'cunderline': underline}">Some text</div>
```

and in component I have:

```
   bold= false;
   underline = true;
   italic = false;
```

and in css I have:

```
   cbold {
     font-weight: bold
   }

   citalic {
     font-style: italic
   }

   cunderline {
     text-decoration: underline;
   }
```

my text will not be underlined. Here is what I get when inspect:

```
   <div _ngcontent-sqd-c0="" class="cunderline" ng-reflect-ng-class="[object Object]">Some text</div>
```

Here is a [stackblitz link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pgndwv)

Is this a known bug, or I am doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a dot in front of your class names in the css file, without a dot you are styling tags.

```
.cbold {
  font-weight: bold
}

.citalic {
  font-style: italic
}

.cunderline {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

Comment: My bad, thanks, I thought the problem was in ng-reflect-ng-class="[object Object]"

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to add `.` in the css before the class names.

```
 .cbold {
     font-weight: bold
   }

   .citalic {
     font-style: italic
   }

   .cunderline {
     text-decoration: underline;
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

you are not using class selector.

```
.cbold {
     font-weight: bold
   }

   .citalic {
     font-style: italic
   }

   .cunderline {
     text-decoration: underline;
   }
```